# javascript loading problem

Tags: javascript

When i am trying to write the code like 
document.getElementById('id1') after teh script tag it is showing document.getElementById(..) null or not an object..
Is it necessary to write document.getElementById('id1') in function only.
If i write this code in function then it is accepting. So what the mistake here..
and if i want to execute a function on loading of the page where to write onLoad() function.. i try to write at  but it is not loading.. please help me
Thank you

Comment: sorry... onLoad() try to write at form tag but it is not working..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to be sure that your dom element is loaded, you have to wait the document is loaded.

To do this you can do:

```
<head>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function foo(){
          var elem = document.getElementById("yourElem");
        //...
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="foo()">...</body>
```

or

```
<head>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function foo(){
         var elem = document.getElementById("yourElem");
        //...
        }

        window.onload = foo;
    </script>
</head>
<body>...</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want the script to run after the page is loaded, you can use window.onload.

```
<script>
window.onload = function () {
    //code goes here
}
.
.
.
</script>
```

Comment: thank you so much.. then what about document.getElementById('someid')

Comment: @Mihir, I don't understand what you want. I recommend using console in FireBug (for Firefox) or Developer tools (for Chrome/Safari), if you are playing with DOM.

Answer (score 0):

Put your script bellow the element you are getting will also work.

```
<div id="ele"></div>
<script language="javascript">
    alert(document.getElementById('ele').tagName);
</script>
<div id="ele1"></div>
```

But unless you have special purpose, it's a good habit to write handlers in after document loaded, that is, put your code in window.onload event handler.